# How can I read specific columns from a given record in VB.NET and MySql 8?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to read a given record from a MySql Database using VB.NET. I am specifically retrieving four columns from table `customer` for a given `id`.

I have seen in MySQL logs how the query reaches the server and when I execute that directly on a SQL window in MySQL it works, so I assume that the issue is on the code used in VB.NET.

I specifically get an error while trying to retrieve the specific columns into variables.

I have tried this:

```vb
    Dim query As String = "SELECT 
        IFNULL(name, ''),
        IFNULL(type, 0),
        IFNULL(street, ''),
        IFNULL(postalcode, ''),
        IFNULL(town, ''),
    FROM customer WHERE 
        id = @id;"

    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(Database.ConnectionString)
        Using comm As New MySqlCommand()
            With comm
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = query
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
                reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.Read() Then
                    Name = reader("name")
                    Type = reader("type")
                    Address = reader("street")
                    PostalCode = reader("postalcode")
                    Town = reader("town")
                End If
                reader.Close()

            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

And I get:

```
Name = reader("name")
Exception Unhandled
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Could not find specified column in results: name'
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly as the error message says: there's no column in the result set of your data reader called "name".  Look at your query.  You're not retrieving the `name` column; you're retrieving the result of the `IFNULL` function.  As such, the corresponding column in your result set will not be autoamtically named "name".  You need to specify an alias if you expect the result of an expression to have a name.

Comment: Thanks, just for the record, I added  `AS name`, `AS type`, etc. in the query to create an alias